# Show that the sequence $(s_n) = ((-1)^n n)$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that $(s_n)$ diverges. Since every convergent sequence is bounded, all I have to do is prove that $(s_n)$ is unbounded. But how?

Comment: What is the definition of unbounded that you're trying to work with? A minor simplification: consider $n = 2k$ even. Can you give me some $n$ for which $s_n > 100000000000000000000000$?

Comment: Suppose the sequence is bounded by some $M$. Try to get a contradiction from this.

Comment: Hint : There is no lower bound since there are infinite many odd numbers and no upper bound since there are infinite many even numbers.

Comment: Thanks for all tips. @guidoar A sequence $(s_n)$ is bounded if exists $r>0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|s_n| < r$. A sequence is unbounded iff it is not bounded. EBP, if there exists such $M$, then if n is even, $|(-1^n)n| = |n| < r$ and on the other hand if n is odd then $|(-1^n)n| = |-n| < r$. Got stuck here, but I'll try to figure it out. Peter, thanks for the tip, but the exercise requires me to use bounded sequences definition.

Comment: The sequence is bounded indeed $\log [ (-1) ^n n] = n \log(-1) + n = -n+n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to write down a more tractable definition of unbounded. Negating the definition of bounded means that for each $r >  0$ we should be able to find some $n$ for which $|s_n| \geq r$.

Note that, by archimedianity, if we can do this for $r \in \mathbb N$ we can do it for any $r$ (by doing it for a larger number which is natural). Think about this for a while if it is not clear at first.

So, given $r \in \mathbb N$, can you find $n \geq 1$ such that $|s_n| \geq r$?

Answer (score 0):

$|s_{n}| = n$. Imagine $s_{n}$ was bounded above and below by $M_{1}, M_{2}$ respectively, then $|s_{n}|< max(|M_{1}|, |M_{2}|)$, however choosing $n= \ceiling{max(|M_{1}|, |M_{2}|)}$ we get a contradiction. Thus $s_{n}$ is unbounded.